# Filter is not working on Pandas Date Index

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a DF with Index as Date column, when i try to filter DF by Index as sales_df['2020'] it's throwing below error. [image: Error] Ideally i should be able to filter by Year or Month or Day when Index is Date. Could you tell me what's going on here?

[image: DataFrame]

Comment: Please paste your actual code and data as text, not as images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sales_df['2020']` is used to select the `2020` column from the data frame, which obviously wouldn't work for your data frame.

To filter rows using a date time index, use

```
df.loc['2020'] # which returns nothing for your data set
```

Or something like

```
df.loc['2010-02':'2010-09']
```

```
                  Date  Store
Date                         
2010-02-12  2010-02-12      1
2010-09-10  2010-09-10      1
```